# EFI_TIMEOUT error on EFI_TCG2_SUBMIT_COMMAND

Tags: c, uefi, tpm

Inside EFI I use **EFI_TCG2_PROTOCOL** to communicate with TPM device.

On system start I decrypt some data calling TPM device commands with function **EFI_TCG2_SUBMIT_COMMAND** in protocol **EFI_TCG2_PROTOCOL**. That works fine.

But now (seems that after windows update) I started to receive error **EFI_TIMEOUT** (0x8000000000000012) on my attempts to execute command with **EFI_TCG2_SUBMIT_COMMAND**.

What can be the possible reason? How to fix it?

Comment: Have you a dTPM or an fTPM?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is the TPM still accessible from windows?